# How can I calculate the $x$ and $y$ coordinate for the center of mass of a bounded region?

Tags: calculus

Consider the region bounded by the three curves:

$$\begin{aligned} &y=\frac{2x}{5}\\ &y=1\\ & x=x_0 \end{aligned}$$

Assuming a homogenous distribution of mass, the formula for the coordinates of the center of mass that I was given are: $$\begin{aligned}& x_s=\frac{1}{A}\int_A x \space dA \\ & y_s=\frac{1}{A} \int _A y \space dA\end{aligned}$$

> 1. Calculate the center of mass for $x=-0.5$
> 2. For what $x_0$ is the center of mass on the $x$-axis. What is $x_s$ in this case?

**My attempt:**

I tried to sketch the curves and the bounded region first:

[image]

So I am trying to find the coordinates of the center of mass of the triangle. But how do I use those formulas? Are $x$ and $y$ in the integral functions?

Comment: Your formulas look wrong, the symbol $A$ is being used in three mutually contradictory ways.

Comment: Should be $\frac{1}{m} \int_A x\; \text{d}S$ for the center of mass in x direction, where $m$ is the total mass of the object.

Comment: @LeeMosher Hi. That's the way it is formulated on our assignment. I triple checked that I copied it correctly. What exactly is the problem with the formula?

Comment: You write $\frac{1}{A}$ as if $A$ was some scalar value. Then you do integration over $A$ with $\int_A$ but at the same time integrate with respect to $A$ ($\text{d}A$), which is a bit weird.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it except that it is slightly sloppy. The $\frac{1}{A}$ refers to the total area of the triangle. The $\int_A\dots dA$ means that you are integrating over the triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D$ be the region described.  Since the density is uniform, can assume it's constantly one.  The “mass” of the region $D$ is the same as its area,
$$
m = \iint_D 1\,dA = \int_{x_0}^{5/2} \int_{2x/5}^1 1\,dy\,dx
$$
The $x$-coordinate of the center of mass is
$$
\bar x =\frac{1}{m} \iint_D x\,dA = \frac{1}{m}\int_{x_0}^{5/2} \int_{2x/5}^1 x\,dy\,dx
$$
and the $y$-coordinate is
$$
\bar y =\frac{1}{m} \iint_D y\,dA = \frac{1}{m}\int_{x_0}^{5/2} \int_{2x/5}^1 y\,dy\,dx
$$

To answer one of your questions: yes, the $x$ and $y$ in the integrals are functions.  You can antidifferentiate a function of two variables with respect to one of them just like you can differentiate a function of two variables with respect to one of them.  That is, you treat the “other” variable as a constant.

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thank you very much. I am just working through it. How did you get the first line? Is that the standard formula for mass?

Comment: @bluemoon: The standard formula for total mass is the integral of density, yes.  Since the density is uniform we'll just assume it's one. (if that seems strange, notice that if the density is not one, but some other constant $\rho$, we would need it in the other integrals, too.  But $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ will then have a $\rho$ in the numerator and denominator.

Comment: Thank you. Just one more question relating to integration. Does the double integral $$\int_{x_0}^{5/2}\int_{2x/5}^1 1 dy dx$$ mean that I integrate $$\int_{2x/5}^1 1 dy$$ first and then integrate that result from $x_0$ to $\frac{5}{2}$ with respect to $x$?

Comment: @bluemoon.  Yes, that's exactly what that means.  Read your textbook's section on double versus iterated integrals for more information.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I am confident I can figure it out now.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

The answer of Matthew Leingang is general.  In your case the region is a triangle so you can find the centroid (that coincides with the center of mass since the density is constant) using the fact that the [coordinates of the centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Of_triangle_and_tetrahedron) are the  means of the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: Cool hint. I think I will do it both ways because I think the assignement is specifically made for practicing with (and asks us to use) the "general formula". Your way is significantly shorter though so I am sure I will need it in the future. Thanks!